# Text-based RPG in Python 3 error - keyword cant be used as an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

import random

class Item():
    """The base class for all items"""
    def **init**(self, name, description, value):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.value = value
        self.quality = quality

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\n".format(self.name, self.description, self.value)
```

class Gold(Item):
    def **init**(self, amt):
        self.amt = amt
        super().**init**(name="Gold",
                         description="A round coin with {} stamped on the front.".format(str(self.amt)),
                         value=self.amt)

class Weapon(Item):

```
Conditions = { 1 : "Bad Condition",  2 : "Bad Condition",
               3 : "Good Condition", 4 : "Good Condition",
               5 : "Perfect Condition" }

def __init__(self, name, description, value, damageRange):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.value = value
    self.condition = Weapon.Conditions[self.damage]
    self.qualtiy = damage
```

class Rock(Weapon):
    def **init**(self):
        super().**init**("Rock",
                         "A fist-sized rock, suitable for bludgeoning.",
                         0,
                         range(1,5))

class Dagger(Weapon):
    def **init**(self):
        super().**init**("Dagger",
                         "A small dagger with some rust. Somewhat more dangerous than a rock.",
                         10,
                         range(5,11))

class Longsword(Weapon):
    def **init**(self):
        super().**init**("Longsword",
                         "A sword forged by the legendary blacksmith Ailred Gilric",
                         15,
                         range(15,20))

error - AttributeError: 'Longsword' object has no attribute 'damage'

Comment: The error message is missing?

Comment: If you call a super() it might be beneficial to also supply the super-class (`Weapon`) - also provide the exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how function parameters work. For instance, the `quality=damage` line is wrong - `damage` doesn't exist at that point, the previous line `damage=random` is setting a parameter, not assigning a variable. Also you can't use numbers as parameter names, so the 1 ... 5 lines are invalid syntax

Comment: Please use correct formatting.  This is too difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reference params that you gave in-line:

> ```
> super().__init__(name="Rock",
>                      description="A fist-sized rock, suitable for bludgeoning.",
>                      value=0,
>                      damage=random.randint(1,5), 
>                      1 = "Bad Condition",  # does not work, you could put them into a
>                                            # dict and provide that.
>                      2 = "Bad Condition",
>                      3 = "Good Condition",
>                      4 = "Good Condition",
>                      5 = "Perfect Condition",
>                      quality = damage)     # can not reference damage here, damage is
>                                            # the keyword the exception complains about
> ```

You can solve this like so:

```
import random

class Weapon:
    # this is a shared class variable for all weapons and maps a damage-value
    # to a textual condition
    Conditions = { 1 : "Bad Condition",  2 : "Bad Condition",
                   3 : "Good Condition", 4 : "Good Condition",
                   5 : "Perfect Condition" }

    def __init__(self,name,desc,value,dmgRange):
        self.name = name 
        self.description = desc
        self.value = value
        # switched to random.choice() over the given range
        self.damage = random.choice(dmgRange)
        self.condition = Weapon.Conditions[self.damage]
        self.quality = self.damage

class Rock(Weapon):

    # condition and quality are dependent on the damage, moved them into the
    # base classes __init__
    # moved the random damage also into the base class, so it decides on the damage
    # you would have to replicate that make a random damage in each weapon...  
    def __init__(self):
        # range(1,6) : 6 is exclusive, so you get 1,2,3,4,5
        super().__init__("Rock","A fist-sized rock, suitable for bludgeoning.",
                         0,range(1,6))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"A {self.name} in {self.condition}. Its quality rates {self.quality} " \
               + f"and it deals {self.damage} damage. It cost: {self.value} coins."

print("You inspect the beach and find:")
for _ in range(10):
    print("-",Rock())
```

Output:

```
You inspect the beach and find:
- A Rock in Perfect Condition. Its quality rates 5 and it deals 5 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Bad Condition. Its quality rates 1 and it deals 1 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Bad Condition. Its quality rates 2 and it deals 2 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Good Condition. Its quality rates 4 and it deals 4 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Good Condition. Its quality rates 4 and it deals 4 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Bad Condition. Its quality rates 1 and it deals 1 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Good Condition. Its quality rates 4 and it deals 4 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Bad Condition. Its quality rates 2 and it deals 2 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Bad Condition. Its quality rates 2 and it deals 2 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
- A Rock in Good Condition. Its quality rates 4 and it deals 4 damage. It cost: 0 coins.
```

Readup:

- [`dict`ionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)
- [`range(start,stop[,step]`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) - look at `__repr__()` as well, you might want to change that one too

Comment: I realised that i messed up - i have attributes of 1 to 5 but if i want anything to have a damage of over 5 it doesn't work

Comment: You need to adapt the quality dictionary for that - or simply add additional damage to in your init-method: `self.damage = random.choice(dmgRange) + 5`